# Chrome Native App Install Banner

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

The Native App Install Banner doesn't let us know if user has cancelled or installed the Native App in mobile devices, by using the below code. Please Help.

```
deferredPrompt.userChoice.then(function(choiceResult) {
    console.log('User Choice!'); 
    console.log(choiceResult.outcome);
    choiceElement.textContent = choiceResult.outcome;

    if(choiceResult.outcome == 'dismissed') {
    console.log('Cancelled Install');
    }
    else {
    console.log('User added to homescreen');
    }

    // We no longer need the prompt. Clear it up.
    deferredPrompt = null;
   });
```

Comment: Can you explain more? How does it not let you know if the user cancelled? If It's dismissed you would get a console message.

Comment: In Case of native app install banner (Not Progressive Web app add to home screen), the dismissed or installed events doesn't get fired